# Media Projection and Image Reader duo not working on Netflix/Youtube on Android TV

Tags: youtube, android-tv, netflix, image-reader, mediaprojection

Media Projection and Image Reader duo not working on Netflix/Youtube on Android TV.

I am trying to get image from android TV with Media Projection and Image Reader.

On the log side, a warning catches my eye; probably because Image Reader uses OpenGL:

```
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xd7995a68 disconnect failed
```

Although it works correctly in the simulator, Image Reader does not work properly in programs such as Youtube, Netflix and so on licensed Android TV. (No problem in simulator)

I tried, works fine on CNBC-e and Android TV User Interface.

***I'm starting to think it's due to HDCP.*** Any guesses about it? Or do you think these programs have Media Projection protection?

Images captured on Netflix and Youtube are always the same. It's like time has stopped.

The heart of my codes is as follows.

```
private class ImageAvailableListener implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try (Image image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage()) {
                if (image != null) {
                    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = (ByteBuffer) planes[0].getBuffer().rewind();
                    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * mWidth;

                    // create bitmap
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

                    // write bitmap to a file
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(mStoreDir + "/myscreen_" + IMAGES_PRODUCED + ".png");
                    resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                    IMAGES_PRODUCED++;
                        Log.e(TAG, "captured image: " + IMAGES_PRODUCED);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }

            }
        }
    }

@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private void createVirtualDisplay() {
        // get width and height
        mWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        mHeight = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        // start capture reader
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
        mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(SCREENCAP_NAME, mWidth, mHeight,
                mDensity, getVirtualDisplayFlags(), mImageReader.getSurface(), null, mHandler);
        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageAvailableListener(), mHandler);
    }
```